# JsHelper is doing a POST request by submitting the 2nd time

Tags: cakephp

I have a login dialog window and when the user submits it the 2nd time, a POST request is made, but why?

Here is the Javascript Code:

```
//<![CDATA[
$("#UserLoginSubmit").bind("click", function (event) {$.ajax({beforeSend:function (XMLHttpRequest) {$("#UserLoginForm input").attr("disabled", "disabled"); $(".loading-icon").show();}, completion:"$(\".loading-icon\").hide();", data:$("#UserLoginSubmit").closest("form").serialize(), dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#login-dialog").html(data);}, type:"post", url:"\/prizeplay\/login"});
return false;});
//]]>
```

I gave the submit button a unique Id but I dont know why second request is a POST request...

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some research I found out that the 2nd submission is a black-hole'd one. I dont know really why but after editing the code several times Firebugs says that the 2nd request is an 404 Error with an HTML answer including the "Black-Hole" errors :/